# How to use wildcard in the path to search jsonb values for postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Using postgres version 10.13

This is my datatable jsongraphs

| id | jsongraph |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | { "data": {"scopes_by_id": { "121": { "id": 121, "pk": 121, "name": "Prework" } }, "commonsites_by_id": {"123": {"id": 123, "pk": 123, "name": "Somewhere over the rainbow"}}}} |
| 2 | { "data": {"scopes_by_id": { "156": { "id": 156, "pk": 156, "name": "ABC" } }, "commonsites_by_id": {"123": {"id": 123, "pk": 123, "name": "Somewhere over the rainbow"}}}} |

I want the distinct values of scope id and site id which should be (121, 123), (156,123)

So I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            jsongraph->'data'->'scopes_by_id'->>'pk' ,
            jsongraph->'data'->'commonsites_by_id'->>'pk' from jsongraphs;
```

This won't work because the path should be like `data->scopes_by_id->121->>pk` but I cannot know beforehand the value of 121 in between.

Is there a way to get the values of what I need by filling in some kind of wildcard in the path?

E.g.`data->scopes_by_id->{*}->>pk` like that?

ANd because this is legacy data, it's also hard to change the data itself.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: just updated the question. thanks for reminder. just to reiterate its 10.13

Comment: This will be quite complicated with Postgres 10, but is quite easy with 12 (or later) due to the introduction of SQL/JSON path queries. Is the nesting level fixed or can this contain multiple levels?

Comment: oh... i see. i guess i have to upgrade to postgres 12. I don't quite get the question about nesting level. Can help me understsand with an example?

Comment: Can the key like `scopes_by_id` contain another JSON object that also contains `scope_by_id`?

Comment: You mean like this? `jsongraph->'data'->'scopes_by_id'->'scopes_by_id'->>'pk' ` The answer is no.

if you mean like `jsongraph->'data'->'scopes_by_id'->'123'->'123'->>'pk' ` the answer is also no.

Comment: And what if you have 5 entries for `scopes_by_id` but 20 for `commonsites_by_id` what is the expected output then?

Comment: just take the first of each. originally some had 2 scopes and always 1 site. but now most of the data is 1 scope and 1 site.

Answer (score 2):

As the nesting level seems to be fixed, you could do something like this:

```
select j.id, scopes.*, commonsites.*
from jsongraphs j
  cross join lateral (
     select jsonb_agg(j.jsongraph #> array['data','scopes_by_id', t1.scope_id, 'pk']) as scope_ids
     from jsonb_each_text(j.jsongraph #> '{data,scopes_by_id}') as t1(scope_id)
  ) scopes
  cross join lateral ( 
     select jsonb_agg(j.jsongraph #> array['data','commonsites_by_id', t2.site_id, 'pk']) as common_ids
     from jsonb_each_text(j.jsongraph #> '{data,commonsites_by_id}') as t2(site_id)
  ) commonsites
order by id;
```

The sub-queries extract all key below the respective part (e.g. `scopes_by_id`) and then uses the `#>'` operator to access the path for each id inside the original JSON value. And finally all PK values are aggregated back into a single array.

This returns the PK values from each part separately as an array in order to handle the situation where you have a different number of "scope ids" and "commonsite ids"

If you just want "the first" id from each section, you can remove the aggregation and use a LIMIT clause:

```
select j.id, scopes.*, commonsites.*
from jsongraphs j
  cross join lateral (
     select j.jsongraph #> array['data','scopes_by_id', t1.scope_id, 'pk'] as scope_id
     from jsonb_each_text(j.jsongraph #> '{data,scopes_by_id}') as t1(scope_id)
     limit 1
  ) scopes
  cross join lateral ( 
     select j.jsongraph #> array['data','commonsites_by_id', t2.site_id, 'pk'] as common_id
     from jsonb_each_text(j.jsongraph #> '{data,commonsites_by_id}') as t2(site_id)
     limit 1
  ) commonsites
order by id;
```

Not sure on which level you want to apply the "distinct" part for this.

---

In Postgres 12 or later, you could achieve the same with:

```
select id, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(j.jsongraph, 'strict $.data.scopes_by_id.**.pk') as scopes,
       jsonb_path_query_array(j.jsongraph, 'strict $.data.commonsites_by_id.**.pk') as common
from jsongraphs ;
order by id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ff53605d8884cdb7ec34c1504e3633d1)

Comment: Thank you. the postgres 10 looks really complex. I have to spend some time to move the production database to 13 first. Thank you. I will take some time before i get back to you. :)

Comment: @KimStacks if you just want to take "the first" id of each, just use a `limit 1` in the sub-queries. Then you can also get rid of the aggregation done using `jsonb_agg()`